# CodeIgniter Check for Database Connection and if Session Library is Loaded

Tags: database, codeigniter

Two questions:

1. Is there a way in CodeIgniter to check if a library had been loaded? If the session library is loaded, I want to show a user-specific page.
2. If my database is offline and CodeIgniter is unable to connect, how can I display a custom message to users rather than the default error page?

Answer (score 1):

1. Found [this](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/111890/#565037) on Codeigniter
   forum:

   "If you look in the Loader
   library, in the function
   _ci_load_class, you’ll see that it checks if that class has already
   been loaded, and will only load it
   again if its being assigned to a new
   variable.

   Interestingly enough, if you load
   the same class multiple times, the
   memory usage does go up though"

   So if you call `$this->load->library(LIB_NAME)` more than once, it will only actually load it once. This is from 2009 and CI has been
   updated many times since then so not
   sure if it's still true.
2. I hope your db never goes down. But
   if it does `$CI->db->conn_id`
   returns true if it can connect.

Comment: Regarding #1, I don't want to load my session class, rather I want to display a view file differently if the user is in fact logged in, but I don't want to load the session class and create it. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I don't think a server can know other than using cookies, which is essentially the session class, that a user's logged in from page to page. You need to maintain a user's "state" and show diff pages depending on logged in status. You can avoid the session class by setting your own cookie, but you can't avoid setting cookies.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is best (or even good) practice but I found using something like

```
if(isset($CI->session)):
    //show user specific page
endif;
```

works for me so far, eg. the last 5 mins since I tried it =). In my case I didn't want the debug message:

```
Session class already loaded. Second attempt ignored.
```

polluting my logs, so I used:

```
if(!isset($CI->session)):
    $CI->load->library('session');
endif;
```

hth..